# Using `self` in a class method

Tags: python

Is using the variable name `self` in a classmethod considered bad practice? For example:

```
@classmethod
def update_objs(cls, limit=10e6):
    items = PortalAsset.objects.filter(is_deleted=False, title__is_active=True)[:limit]
    for self in items:
        new_obj = {
            'objectID': self.pk
        }
        # etc.
```

I find that the above seems more intuitive to me to know that each item in the loop is basically an instance of that Class.

Comment: yes its bad dont do it ... anyone else who has to work with the code will be annoyed to say the least `for portalAsset in items:` or even better dont care  `for item in cls.objects.filter(...):new_obj=serialize(item)`

Comment: Given the idiom of `self` usage I don't like the way this reads. I had to reread this 3 times to completely get what was going on. Also do you use the `cls` parameter here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do it. Anyone who has to read your code will want you gone.

Whatever part of the class method you're considering using the name `self` in, consider extracting that out into an instance method. Then you can call the object `self` in that method.

Answer (score 0):

This has more to do with coding conventions, but I believe that if you decide to use the variable `self`, it should have the same reflective meaning as the english word imply, i.e. refers to the current object the code belongs to or something similar.

I however sometimes use that variable in a class method that is supposed to be a constructor:

```
@classmethod
def new_from_file(cls, filename):
    self = cls()
    self.load_file(filename)
    return self
```

Now you ask the question, I wonder if it is that wise. Maybe something else like `new_object` would be better, but I find it quite explicit what is done here, as the `self` variable is really used to hold the current object.